# Element-wise addition of lists in Pyspark Dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have dataframe:

```
data = [{"category": 'A', "bigram": 'delicious spaghetti', "vector": [0.01, -0.02, 0.03], 'all_vector' : 2},
        {"category": 'A', "bigram": 'delicious dinner', "vector": [0.04, 0.05, 0.06], 'all_vector' : 2},
        {"category": 'B', "bigram": 'new blog', "vector": [-0.14, -0.15, -0.16], 'all_vector' : 2},
        {"category": 'B', "bigram": 'bright sun', "vector": [0.071, -0.09, 0.063], 'all_vector' : 2}
        ]

sdf = spark.createDataFrame(data)

+----------+-------------------+--------+---------------------+
|all_vector|bigram             |category|vector               |
+----------+-------------------+--------+---------------------+
|2         |delicious spaghetti|A       |[0.01, -0.02, 0.03]  |
|2         |delicious dinner   |A       |[0.04, 0.05, 0.06]   |
|2         |new blog           |B       |[-0.14, -0.15, -0.16]|
|2         |bright sun         |B       |[0.071, -0.09, 0.063]|
+----------+-------------------+--------+---------------------+
```

I need to element-wise add lists in a `vector` column and divide by `all_vector column` ( i need normalize vector). Then group by `category column`. I wrote an example code but unfortunately it doesn't work:

```
@udf_annotator(returnType=ArrayType(FloatType()))
def result_vector(vector, all_vector):  
    lst = [sum(x) for x in zip(*vector)] / all_vector
    return lst

sdf_new  = sdf\
    .withColumn('norm_vector', result_vector(F.col('vector'), F.col('all_vector')))\
    .withColumn('rank', F.row_number().over(Window.partitionBy('category')))\
    .where(F.col('rank') == 1)
```

I want it this way:

```
+----------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|all_vector|bigram             |category|norm_vector            |vector               |
+----------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------+---------------------+
|2         |delicious spaghetti|A       |[0.05, 0.03, 0.09]     |[0.01, -0.02, 0.03]  |
|2         |delicious dinner   |A       |[0.05, 0.03, 0.09]     |[0.04, 0.05, 0.06]   |
|2         |new blog           |B       |[-0.069, -0.24, -0.097]|[-0.14, -0.15, -0.16]|
|2         |bright sun         |B       |[-0.069, -0.24, -0.097]|[0.071, -0.09, 0.063]|
+----------+-------------------+--------+-----------------------+---------------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `zip_with` function will help you zip two arrays and apply a function element wise. To use the function, we can create an array collection of the arrays in the `vector` column, and use the `aggregate` function. There might also be other simpler ways to do this though.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('vector_collection', func.collect_list('vector').over(wd.partitionBy('cat'))). \
    withColumn('ele_wise_sum', 
               func.expr('''
                         aggregate(vector_collection, 
                                   cast(array() as array<double>), 
                                   (x, y) -> zip_with(x, y, (a, b) -> coalesce(a, 0) + coalesce(b, 0))
                                   )
                         ''')
               ). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +---+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
# |cat|vector               |vector_collection                             |ele_wise_sum                         |
# +---+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
# |B  |[-0.14, -0.15, -0.16]|[[-0.14, -0.15, -0.16], [0.071, -0.09, 0.063]]|[-0.06900000000000002, -0.24, -0.097]|
# |B  |[0.071, -0.09, 0.063]|[[-0.14, -0.15, -0.16], [0.071, -0.09, 0.063]]|[-0.06900000000000002, -0.24, -0.097]|
# |A  |[0.01, -0.02, 0.03]  |[[0.01, -0.02, 0.03], [0.04, 0.05, 0.06]]     |[0.05, 0.030000000000000002, 0.09]   |
# |A  |[0.04, 0.05, 0.06]   |[[0.01, -0.02, 0.03], [0.04, 0.05, 0.06]]     |[0.05, 0.030000000000000002, 0.09]   |
# +---+---------------------+----------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! But why you use coalesce?

Comment: the second input to `aggregate` is an empty array and `null + double = null`